# Cannot resize array using np.resize

Tags: python, numpy

i am trying to resize an array to 150x150 my code is as below

```
def prepare_data(data):
    """ Prepare data for modeling 
        input: data frame with labels und pixel data
        output: image and label array """
    
    image_array = np.zeros(shape=(len(data), 150, 150))
    image_label = np.array(list(map(int, data['emotion'])))
    
    for i, row in enumerate(data.index):
        image = np.fromstring(data.loc[row, 'pixels'], dtype=int, sep=' ')
        image1 = np.resize(image, (150, 150))
        image1 = np.reshape(image, (150, 150))
        image_array[i] = image1
        
    return image_array, image_label
```

when i go to reshape later on in my code i get the following

```
train_images = train_image_array.reshape((train_image_array.shape[0], 150, 150, 1))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 66145536 into shape (28709,150,150,1)
```

you can see from the error that the array hasnt changed size and is still 28708,48,48

I believe im missing something simple but i cant seem to find it

Thanks!

Comment: shape `28709x150x150x1` is `645,952,500` total elements. How can you reshape only `66,145,536` to that shape?

Comment: @Barmar thats my point its obviously not reshaping as it recgonises 66,145,536 and not 645,952,500

Comment: image1 is resized, you're reshaping image

Comment: The `reshape` operation requires that the input and output formats have exactly the same number of cells.  It just changes how the cells are viewed.

Comment: If it could actually do this reshape, where would it get the other 580K values from?

Comment: Are you expecting to change arrays or images from (48,48) to (150,150)?  `np.reshape` can't to that.  `np.resize` can, but it "repeats" in a 1d manner, which is probably not what you want.  If you want an image kind of rescaling, you'll have to use a `resize` from an image module.  Please read, and if necessary, reread, the docs for functions like `np.reshape` and `np.resize`.

Comment: @hpaulj's note is important.  If you are training a model for images, then you can't use `np.resize`.  You need some kind of interpolating resize.  Note that it's often better to use a smaller size for training.  The interpolation introduces artifacts that will skew the training.

Answer (score 0):

In the multi-dimensional array structure, the number of input elements are expected to exactly match the output. There can't be partially filled elements in any of the lowest dimension(leaf level).

In the above example, the input has `66,145,536` elements. The expected output element size 645,952,500 (`28709 * 150 * 150 * 1`) des not match the input size.

Further, in the post, the statement `image1 = np.reshape(image, (150, 150))` can be changed to `image1 = np.reshape(<resized image>, (150, 150))`

An example:

```py
import numpy as np
input_array = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]  # 2 * 2
resized = np.resize(input_array, (3, 6))  # resize to 3 * 6. repeat with values from input_array. fit mismatched size
output_array = np.reshape(resized, (2, 9))  # reshape to 2 * 9
print(output_array)
```

In the above code, `3 * 6` and `2 * 9` are same.

Output:

```py
[[1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1]
 [2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2]]
```

As per [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html), resize creates a new output array. To resize inplace, [ndarray.resize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) can be used.

Comment: Thamks for that! is there anyway to change the input size? The pre trained model i want to use has a minimum input size of 75x75 which was my reason for trying to resize in the first place.

Comment: You should note, @Kyle, that this is not doing resizing in the image sense.  It's just duplicating rows and columns to fill the extra space.  If you're training an image matcher, this would be horrible.